# php running mysql_query in a for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have different paramter of particular mysql query I am running so I need to run them in bunch.. so say

```
$server = 'server_';
for ($a=0 ; $a<5 ; ++$a) {
     $criteria = $server . $a;
     $query1 = 'select blabh blah not important ' . $criteria . 'order by date desc limit 10';
     $query_result = mysql_query($query1);

}
```

**Above only comes back results for server_4**

I naively thought I could just do

```
$query_result .= mysql_query($query1);
```

But clearly that doesn't work.  I hope no one says why don't you run mysql as 
     like '$server%'

I am looking for to see if what I am trying to do is possible. appending.. I guess string append is possible but I perahps simply don't understand what's coming back from mysql?

fetch code sample

```
select * from tableName where server like $criteria order by date desc limit 10
```

=========================================================
code sample

```
$data = array(); 
$dataMaster = array();

   for ( $x = 0; $x <= 8; $x++ ) {
           $server = ‘server_’ . $x;
           $myquery = 'select * from serverTable where  servername like ' . '"' .  $server . '"'  . ' order by date1 desc limit 100';


           $query = mysql_query($myquery);
           if ( ! $query ) {
                   echo mysql_error();
                   die;
           }
           for ( $x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++ ) {
              $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
           }

           $data = array_reverse($data);
            array_push($dataMaster, $data);
   }

   echo json_encode($dataMaster)
```

Comment: Where are you fetching? `$query_result` is only going to be the last iteration.

Comment: so am I just not thinking in mysql way? Is there no way to append to (whatever is coming back from mysql? like array?)

Comment: The `mysql_query` is a result object (I think, haven't used that driver in a while), not a string. You need to fetch it first... or you could use a `union` and do this all in one query.

Comment: fine. So fetch them and add them into one variable(essentially appending). Is that just not possible?

Comment: That should work, does it not? Are you fetching somewhere currently?

Comment: it does not work.. It just fetches the last server_4(probably because first 3 are overwritten from next server_ )

Comment: The fact that you only see the last one indicates that you're overwriting your result variable with each execution rather than appending to it. How to append rather than overwriting depends on how you're fetching the results, which isn't shown in your question.

Comment: Update the question with the code that is fetching. I'd also consider, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html.

Comment: I def don't understand why fetching code is important. It's just like select * from table basically..   All results coming back is basically table..

Comment: you dont need 5 queries, you could do this in one

Comment: @Dagon, yes, I understand as I originally stated to see if I can do it this way. Is this possible?

Comment: mysql_query() returns a resource. so based on the code provided you should not be getting any 'results' at all. there is code missing here, and with out it we cant help.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is NEVER execute a query inside a loop

Comment: just updated.. that's fine.. if I should not do this(meaning, execute query inside of loop and that is the hard rule in mysql, I will abide by that). I am perhaps coding like none mysql person so that is something I will need to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid SQL inside PHP loop, you can do the following instead:

```
SELECT * FROM serverTable WHERE servername IN 
('server_0', 'server_1', 'server_2', 'server_3', 'server_4')
```

Comment: I am also looking at this.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out, this is what I needed. I guess in SQL, you don't run inside of for loop in php and I can see why since I can always do something like this. This got what I needed . thank you and accepted!